# I need help in R Code to create a new column that chooses a column name given a criteria

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a new column which will choose between the five columns (A,B,C,D,E) and its value will the column name where the value is Maximum. How do I do this with R code?

For instance, I need in the picture, the values in the new column should be 'A'

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**fitted** being your dataframe, a solution in base R:

```
fitted$top_column <- 
  apply(fitted, 1, function(xs) names(fitted)[which.max(xs)])
```

... or in "tidyverse" style:

```
library(dplyr)
##

fitted <- fitted %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(top_column = names(.)[which.max(c_across(everything()))])
```

**edit**

the latter breaks down into these operations:

```
fitted <- fitted %>%
  rowwise %>% ## evaluate row by row
  mutate(top_column = names(.) ## (1) 
         [which.max( ## (2)
                    c_across( ##(3)
                      everything()) ## (4)
                    ))])
```

- (1) returns the names of .
  where the point represents the incoming data = dataframe **fitted**
- (2) `which.max` returns the position of the maximum in a vector of values (we thus pick the *n*<sup>th</sup> of the column `names` where *n* is the column index containing the `rowwise` maximum)
- (3) `c_across` applies a *summary* function across selected columns
- (4) `everything` selects all columns to apply the function over (for a broad variety of selection *verbs* like `everything`, `starts_with`, `contains` etc. see [tidyselect](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/articles/syntax.html))

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Could you please explain the code a bit, specifically the tidyverse.

I have used the mutate function before, but never in a way you did here.